# Change hyperlink to something else with js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, hyperlink

What is the best way to change a link like etc this:

```
<a href="replacethislink">button</a>
```

to

```
<a href="#" class="replaced">button</a>
```

With either js or jQuery?

Comment: you want to add a class?

Comment: yes change the attribute and add a class :-)

Comment: You should really show some effort on your side, not just ask us to give you the code you need ...

Comment: Elucius - I'm sure this very thread will be helpfull for allot of ppl ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use,

1. **[`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** for updating `href` attribute
2. **[`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)** for adding the class

```js
$('a[href="replacethislink"]').attr('href', '#').addClass('replaced');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="replacethislink">button</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript (modern browser) :

```
var linkToReplace = document.querySelectorAll('a[href="replacethislink"]');
linkToReplace.setAttribute("href", "#");
linkToReplace.setAttribute("class", "replaced");
```

Using javascript (older browser) :

```
var linkToReplace = null;
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)       {
    if (links[i].getAttribute("href") == "replacethislink") {
        linkToReplace = links[i];
    }
}

if(linkToReplace) {
    linkToReplace.setAttribute("href", "#");
    linkToReplace.setAttribute("class", "replaced");
}
```

Using jQuery :

```
var linkToReplace = $('a[href="replacethislink"]');
linkToReplace.attr("href", "#");
linkToReplace.addClass("replaced");
```

Comment: Have to mention that there is many diffrent links in the page, I just want those with the specific attribute to get the class added.